# React keeps escaping the amp character (&) in attributes

Tags: javascript, css, escaping, reactjs

I have a component with a `data-icon` attribute. The value of this attribute should be, for instance, `&#xf00f` so that css can render it via `content: attr( data-icon );`.

However, whatever I try: React keeps escaping to `&amp;`. Even when I provide the proper unicode character `\u0026#xf00f`.

Is there some way to stop React from messing with that value? Besides dangerously setting inner html, as I do not want to add another wrapper.

**Component**

```
define( [ 'react', 'util' ], function( React, Util )
{
    return React.createClass(
    {
        render: function()
        {
            //var amp = '\u0026',
            var amp = String.fromCharCode( 38 ),    
            // Util.icons[x] returns a String, such as "f00f"
            code = amp + '#x' + Util.icons[this.props.name] + ';';

            return (
                <i data-icon={code}>
                    {this.props.children ? <span>{this.props.children}</span> : null}
                </i>
            );
        }
    } );
} );
```

**Usage**

```
<Widget.Icon name="add" />
```

**Output**

```
<i data-icon="&amp;#xf0fb;" data-reactid=".170lse36465.7.0"></i>
```

Comment: Unfortunately css does not interpret this as an utf8 character when I use the attr() feature. It just prints out the exact same string then.

Comment: Can you post the code for your component, please?

Comment: @limelights I added some details (:

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce it... Can you make a JSFiddle or JSBin that illustrates your problem?

Comment: There you go https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/7277/. Unfortunately in the browser dev tools the generated output seems correct (as the `&amp;` is displayed as `&`), but you can see that the css struggles (It should display an invalid character). With serverside rendering in my app I can see the undesired `&amp;` output in the html source.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/7284/ a minor addition: Switch the return statement to see what should be happening (in a raw string the & is not escaped).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, I just realized, that for my particular use case I can simply get away with:

```
<i data-icon={String.fromCharCode( "f00f" )} />
```

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3769